# Is 1hr layover in Rome enough for a flight from South America to Paris?

Tags: italy, rome, short-connections, fco

I have to travel from South America to Paris in July and I have a layover stop in Rome of 55 minutes. 
The airline already told me that the bags will be checked directly to Paris but I still don't know if I'm going to have to go through customs in Rome.

Anyone knows if 55mins will be enough or if I'm going to have to go through customs? I'm not leaving the airport in Rome, just stopping there on my way to Paris since Alitalia's flights have to stop there.

Comment: Immigration (passport control) since you're entering the Schengen Area a this point, and apparently security checks. You wouldn't go through customs though as you wouldn't even have your luggage. Knowing your nationality would probably help, as passport checks for non-Schengen nationals are often longer than from Schengen nationals.

Comment: Bring a change of clothes (or two) in your hand luggage, in case your checked in luggage doesn't make it to Paris. 55 minutes might be too short of a connection for baggage handing.

Comment: I'd explain the situation to the cabin crew so they might move you to a seat near the exit door, so you will have a better chance to make it.

Answer (score 6):

I have been told by a travel agent: If an airline sold you a ticket with a short connection, the airline thinks it's long enough. If you miss the connection it is the airline's problem – they would have to get you on the next available flight. This is of course assuming both flights are part of the same booking.

Comment: +1 This is right. If the airline sold the tickets, then this is their responsibility to find you another flight if you aren't able to make the connection.

Comment: Yes, but even if the airline is responsible to find you a ticket for a later flight (it does not have to be the next flight), it's your own pity if you miss a planned appointment or have to spend parts of your holiday in an airport terminal waiting for the replacement flight.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Yes, if a possible delay arriving at your final destination is going to be a big problem, then change your flight. I'm not saying I would recommend booking a flight with a short connection, but now it's done I wouldn't worry too much about it. Unless as you say it will be a huge problem if you are delayed for a few hours. Fortunately there are quite a few Alitalia flights from Rome to Paris every day so it's not likely you would have to wait too long to get on another flight.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [you would have to go through a security check](http://www.adr.it/es/web/aeroporti-di-roma-en-/pax-fco-flight-connections) since you come from a non-schengen country.

55 minutes might be too little time if the control takes more time than expected but it should be enough since you don't have to check in anything.

Comment: I don't have to check-in any bags, they told me my bags will go directly from South America to Paris.
My experience with security checks has always been without problems, if my flight is about to depart, they usually make you skip the line and go right through security. Do you think this will be the case?

Thank you for your quick reply and help!

Comment: @fjb91 I know, but you would have to clear the security check anyhow.

Comment: On top of a security check, there's also immigration (passport check).

Comment: In my opinion, you can just politely ask the guards/people before you to kindly let you pass, since you are going to miss your flight. I am positive that nobody will neglect you the courtesy.